# Doesn't search attribute on JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have input text. I need search elemetn by title! No id and class. I have code, but it doesn't work. So how it's fixed?

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
Phone: <input type="text" name="Phone" title="title1" value="(XXX) XXX-XXXX"><br>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
var test=$(this).attr('title','title1');
test.text("(999) 999-9999");    
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [attributes selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) lets you select elements based on attributes, the way you're doing it now, you're setting a title attribute on the document

```
var test = $('[title="title1"]');
test.val("(999) 999-9999");
```

and for inputs, the value is set with `val()`, not `text()`

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/M6QDY/)

Comment: @user2956406 - you were setting attribute in your code, this is how you search for attribute

Comment: even better var test= $('input[title="title1"]');

Comment: Why would it be better to add the tagname ?

Comment: @adeneo: Less work for the browser to do.  It can only look at `<input>` tags, not every tag.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - jQuery selectors are generally read from right to left, so I would think it would be more work for the browser ?

Comment: @adeneo: Right to left?  Really?  Are you sure?

Comment: @RocketHazmat - pretty sure, that's generally how it works in CSS and javascript.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - You Googled it didn't you :-). Thought I was pulling your chain. It first finds all elements with the matching title, then filters them on tagnames, which is less efficient, and shouldn't be done unless you actually need to filter on tagname.

Comment: @adeneo: I did google it.  It's not that I didn't believe you, but I had jsut never heard that before, so I was curious.  I found: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-think-right-to-left-with-jquery/ :-D

Comment: @RocketHazmat - I have to admit, the attributes selector is somewhat special, and it could be that it works the other way around, haven't checked it, but I would think it's read from right to left, like any other selector, but I'm not sure ?

Comment: @adeneo: You're probably right, I'd assume it is too.  I thought it was left-to-right, though.  Never would've thought it wasn't!

Comment: @RocketHazmat - The perfomance difference is not noticeable anyway, but generally it's less efficient to add the tagname in selectors, so MaiKaY's comment is basically wrong.